# How to Sort Mongo collection in F#

Tags: mongodb, f#

I can get a collection in MongoDB using F# No problem using

```
let draws = db.GetCollection<Draw>("draws").Find(fun _ -> true)
```

To Sort I would expect it to be:

```
let draws = db.GetCollection<Draw>("draws").Find(fun _ -> true).Sort(Builders<Draw>.Sort.Descending(d => d.drawDate))
```

But I am getting the following error.  In the intellisense all of the types seem to be recognised all the way through so I am not sure what to do.

A unique overload for method 'Descending' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.

Comment: Should it be `fun d -> d.drawDate` instead of `d => d.drawDate`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin yes you are right, I had tried it both ways though - I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second lambda is using C# syntax. I'm not sure if that's what's causing the compiler error, but I think it's easier to do something like this anyway:

```ml
let draws =
    db.GetCollection<Draw>("draws")
        .Find(fun _ -> true)
        .SortByDescending(fun d -> d.drawDate :> obj)
```

(Note that the `SortByDescending` function requires a result of explicit type `object`, but it shouldn't cause any problems for you. I think this is because the driver was created with C# clients in mind, where the upcast is implicit.)

Comment: Genius.  thank you!  I have switched from Typescript after a few years ( previously O/O in C# ) and loving the F# language and FP concepts.  Just a few gotchas here and there though!

Comment: Happy to help out. Welcome to F#. :)